# vba: evaluating whether sql statement is true or false

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba

how do i evaluate in VBA access whether the following statement is true:

```
([Panels] like '*IT_AMPH,*' or [Panels] like '*AMPH_SN,*' or [Panels] like '*AMPH_S,*') and
([Panels] like '*IT_BARB,*' or [Panels] like '*BARB_SN,*' or [Panels] like '*BARB_S,*')
```

this is going to be running in `Report_Load` and i need to know whether the statement returns true or false

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See whether the IIf() function works here.

```
IIf("your long statement", 1, 0)
```

Comment: Yes.  You can us IIf in VBA code as well as in SQL statements.  The two IIf flavors are not exactly the same, but pretty darn close for many purposes.